# Drop duplicate rows from a pandas DataFrame whose timestamps are within a specified range or duration

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
Subject Verb    Object  Date
---------------------------------
Bill    Ate     Food    7/11/2015
Steve   Painted House   8/12/2011
Bill    Ate     Food    7/13/2015
Steve   Painted House   8/25/2011
```

I would like to drop all duplicates, where a duplicate is defined as having the same Subject, Verb, Object, and **falls within an X day range** (in my example: 5 days).

```
Subject Verb    Object  Date
---------------------------------
Bill    Ate     Food    7/11/2015
Steve   Painted House   8/12/2011
Steve   Painted House   8/25/2011
```

Neither instance of "Steve - Painted - House" is removed because they are outside of a 5 day window.

I know I can do this using some data structures and the iterrows method of the DataFrame, but is there a way to do this using Pandas drop_duplicates?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `duplicated` + `diff` in conjunction with `groupby` to figure out what rows you want to remove.

```
c = ['Subject', 'Verb', 'Object']

def f(x):
    return x[c].duplicated() & x.Date.diff().dt.days.lt(5)

df = df.sort_values(c)
df[~df.groupby(c).apply(f).values]

  Subject     Verb Object       Date
0    Bill      Ate   Food 2015-07-11
1   Steve  Painted  House 2011-08-12
3   Steve  Painted  House 2011-08-25
```

Comment: Your edited version, where you do not call df.columns.difference, is an improvement, as this allows for there to be other columns in the DataFrame that aren't included in the duplicate criteria.

Comment: @mikeronayne Thanks, I've refactored my answer hoping it's better for you. :)

Comment: maybe `np.close`?