# Pandas identify duplicates and parent duplicate based on specific time range

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like:

[image]

```
ID Amount Date
1   23    3/1/2021 12:00PM
1   23    3/1/2021 12:01PM
1   23    3/1/2021 12:05PM
1   23    3/1/2021 12:09PM
1   24    3/2/2021 12:05PM
2   43    3/1/2021 12:00PM
2   43    3/1/2021 12:01PM
2   432   3/1/2021 12:05PM
```

I want to identify duplicates within a specific time window(5 minutes or less).
In addition to finding the duplicates, I need to count the number of duplicates within that group and label the parent duplicate.

The preliminary output which I have are:

[image]

The output which I want is:

[image]

I referred below links to get the preliminary output but struggling to find the desired output:

1. [pandas dataframe: duplicates based on column and time range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44777114/pandas-dataframe-duplicates-based-on-column-and-time-range)
2. [Drop duplicate rows from a pandas DataFrame whose timestamps are within a specified range or duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47341275/drop-duplicate-rows-from-a-pandas-dataframe-whose-timestamps-are-within-a-specif)

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
df.groupby(['Id',pd.Grouper(key='Date',freq = '5min')]).agg(Amount = ('Amount','first'),
                                                          HaveDuplicates = ('Amount',lambda x: x.duplicated().any()),
                                                          Count_Duplicate = ('Amount',lambda x: x.duplicated().sum()))
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply. If the time window is less than 5min? will it apply in this case?

Comment: This code is skipping those values which are under 5min and are looking in 5min intervals.